# change/remove the previous history url when navigated to another page in chrome

Tags: javascript

I need to change/remove the previous history URL action, when I navigated to another page in chrome . When I clicked back button of chrome or press the shortcut key **Alt+left Arrow**

I have tried this code it wont work

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    alert("Current location: " + location.href);

    var data = e.state;
    if(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e.state));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `window.location.replace(url);` before you navigate to another page.

From MDN:

> "The Location.replace() method replaces the current resource with the
>   one at the provided URL. The difference from the assign() method is
>   that after using replace() the current page will not be saved in
>   session History, meaning the user won't be able to use the back button
>   to navigate to it."

See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace

Good luck!